# Microsoft SQL Server - Joining based on Start DateTime and EndDateTime with a Cumulative Sum

Tags: sql-server, datetime, join, between, cumulative-sum

I am looking to determine the number of users that are logged in to a server at any given time. I have user level data with the start date time and end date time.

**Table 1**

```
user_ID          start_time           end_time
----------------------------------------------------------
1XbC34          03/06/2016 00:00:06   03/06/2016 00:23:26
2re56           03/06/2016 00:01:07   03/06/2016 00:32:40
sdf4ser1w       03/06/2016 00:02:10   03/06/2016 00:02:37
sf54fw3fa       03/06/2016 00:02:11   03/06/2016 00:25:42
fa31f1asf1      03/06/2016 00:04:17   03/06/2016 00:05:43
gvf5af13a       03/06/2016 00:04:18   03/06/2016 00:05:30
f2s14fs3afd1a   03/06/2016 00:04:33   03/06/2016 00:05:07
sdf1a3f1d3sa    03/06/2016 00:04:34   03/06/2016 00:23:02
```

The output I am look for is

```
DateTime              Logged in accumulative (between Start and end)  
--------------------------------------------
03/06/2016 00:00:06,  1
03/06/2016 00:01:07,  2
03/06/2016 00:02:10,  3
03/06/2016 00:02:11,  4
03/06/2016 00:04:17,  4
```

etc...

My initial thinking was to create a temp table that would hold all the date/time to join against table 1 as shown below.

```
select dt.Start_time
into #cal
from table1 dt
where dt.start_time between '2016-06-03 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-03 23:59:59'
group by dt.start_time
```

The next would be to create the join.

```
Select dt.Start_Time, count(*)
from table1 dt
left Join #cal C on C.start_time between dt.start_time AND dt.end_time 
where dt.start_time between '2016-06-03 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-03 23:59:59'
group by dt.start_time
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: I *assumed* that by "Microsoft SQL" you actually mean "Microsoft **SQL Server**" and added the relevant tag for this (it could *also* mean SQL in Microsoft Access - but that doesn't seem likely). Please **always** provide a relevant, useful tag for your actual RDBMS in use - `sql` is just the query language, used by many many databases and thus isn't really very helpful ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a derived table with the start and end times on different rows and a flag indicating starting or ending.  Then a cumulative sum of that flag gives you the information you want.

In SQL Server 2012+, this looks like:

```
select t1.t, sum(inc) over (order by t) as num_users
from ((select start_time as t, 1 as inc from table1) union all
      (select end_time, -1 as inc from table1)
     ) t1;
```